# Flutter web: Deliver raw file to browser for RSS feed

Tags: flutter, rss

I am developing a Web App in Flutter that offers a news section. If the user calls the url "/feed" I would like to deliver the RSS feed of these news.

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'My News page',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const MyHomePage(),
        '/feed': (context) => const RSSFeed(),
      },
);
```

I am looking for a way to take my RSS feed contained in a string and just dump this content to the browser.

Is that at all possible of would this require the flutter app replacing its own page and is therefore not feasible?

Best regards

Olf